# Convergence of sequence of functions under metric iff sequence converges uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $C[0,\infty)$ be the space of continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$. The "sup" norm on this space is too strong, as it eliminates all functions which are unbounded at infinity. Instead, we use the follow metric $\rho_\infty$. Let $s_n(f,g)=\sup_{x\in[0,n]}|f(x)-g(x)|$ and $\rho_n(f,g)=\frac{s_n(f,g)}{1+s_n(f,g)}$. Then, 
$$
\rho_\infty(f,g)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}\rho_n(f,g).
$$
a) Prove that $\rho_\infty$ is a metric.

b) Prove that $f_n \rightarrow f$ under $\rho_\infty$ if and only if functions $\{f_n\}$ converge uniformly to $f$ on every finite interval.

c) Prove that $(C[0,\infty),\rho_\infty)$ is a complete space.

So far I have done a) without much trouble but I am struggling on b) and c). Here's my work so far for b)

**Work**

"$\Rightarrow$"Let $f_n \rightarrow f$ under $\rho_\infty$ then $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \eta \in \mathbb{N}:\forall n \geq \eta$ we have $\rho_\infty(f_n,f)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}\rho_k(f_n,f) < \epsilon$. Assume $\{f_n\}$ does not converge uniformly to $f$ on some interval $[0,m]$. Then $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $s_m(f_n,f)=\sup_{x\in [0,m]}|f_n(x)-f(x)| > \delta$. This holds for all $r \geq m$.

This is where I am stuck, I am trying to find a relationship for $\rho_m$ and then with $\rho_\infty$ but nothing I can come with sticks. I would gladly appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: for (c) you need to find a Cauchy sequence whose limit is not in $C[0,\infty)$.

Comment: It might be easier to prove directly that $\rho_\infty (f_n,f) \to 0 \iff \rho_k(f_n,f)\to 0 \forall k$.

Comment: Also note that converges on every finite interval **iff** $\rho_k(f_n,f) \to 0$ for each $k$.

Comment: @copper.hat Can you elaborate on that a bit? I do not see it. Sorry, I have just woken up and not had enough coffee :)

Comment: Note that ... converges uniformly on $[0,m]$ **iff** $\rho_m(f_n,f) \to 0$. And that every (relevant) interval is contained in some $[0,m]$.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.

Comment: Yes I have figured that the converges on every finite interval **iff** $\rho_k(f_n,f) \rightarrow 0$ for each $k$. Otherwise, we have a sum of fix number greater than $0$ and it diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $f,g$ fixed, $s_n(f,g)$ is increasing with $n$ and $g : x \mapsto \frac{x}{1+x}$ strictly increasing continuously from $0$ to $1$ as $x$ increases from $0$ to $\infty$. Therefore for $N \in \mathbb N$

$$\begin{aligned}
\rho_\infty(f,g)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}\rho_k(f,g) &\ge \frac{1}{2^{N+1}}g(s_{N+1}(f,g))+\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{2^k}\rho_k(f,g)\\
&\ge \frac{1}{2^{N+1}}g(s_{N+1}(f,g))
\end{aligned}$$

Taking a finite interval $I$, it exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $I \subset [0,N]$. Applying previous inequality with $f,f_n$ we get

$$0 \le \frac{1}{2^{N+1}}g(s_{N+1}(f,f_n)) \le \rho_\infty(f,f_n).$$

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \rho_\infty(f,f_n)=0$ implies $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} g(s_{N+1}(f,f_n))=0$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} s_{N+1}(f,f_n)=0$ with what was said about $g$ above. Allowing to prove b). c) follows from b).